# How to reference a local volume in Kind (kubernetes in docker)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, local-storage, kind

I'd like to set up a Persistent Volume (PV and PVC) shared by pods in a [kind cluster](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/). However, I need to ensure that the data is persisted on my laptop (host server) as well. Therefore, the volume's path should be on my laptop that I can directly access.

If I delete the `kind cluster`, the volume should be persisted and not destroyed.

I also want to be able to easily add, update, or copy files from that volume on my host laptop.

How can I make the pods in the `Kind cluster` aware of this setup?

Please find my `kind.yaml` file for your reference.

```
$ kind
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
- role: worker
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you create your kind cluster you can [specify host directories to be mounted on a virtual node](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-mounts).  If you do that, then you can configure volumes with `hostPath` storage, and they will refer to the mount paths on the node.

So you would create a kind config file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraMounts:
      - hostPath: /home/bill/work/foo
        containerPath: /foo
```

and then run

```sh
kind create cluster --config kind-config.yaml
```

to create the cluster.

In your Kubernetes YAML file, you need to mount that `containerPath` as a "host path" on the node.  A pod spec might contain in part:

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: foo
    hostPath:
      path: /foo  # matches kind containerPath:
containers:
  - name: foo
    volumeMounts:
      - name: foo
        mountPath: /data  # in the container filesystem
```

Note that this setup is extremely specific to kind.  Host paths aren't reliable storage in general: you can't control which node a pod gets scheduled on, and both pods and nodes can get deleted in real-world clusters.  In some hosted setups (AWS EKS, Google GKE) you may not be able to control the host content at all.

You might revisit your application design to minimize the need for "files" as first-class objects.  Rather than "update the volume" consider deploying a new Docker image with updated content; rather than "copy files out" consider an HTTP service you can expose through an ingress controller.

Comment: is the `extraMounts` only for that node or for all nodes? For example, my kind lucster has  one master with 3 workers (nodes). Will `/foo` be accessible by all nodes?

Comment: ok, I double checked, that folder `/foo` is only mounted to that node (in our sample, it is in control-plane node).

Comment: If your kind cluster has multiple nodes, you'll have the same problems with `hostPath` as in other multi-node environments.  You can work around this in this context by mounting the same physical-host directory into each node, but this is in general a reason to avoid `hostPath` if you can.

Comment: good idea. mount the same hostPath into multiple nodes. will try it

Comment: @DavidMaze not sure if you'll be able to help; it doesn't seem to work at all for me. I posted my configuration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66104596/share-local-directory-with-kind-kubernetes-cluster-using-hostpath. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Bill what was your final config? I'm having the same issue; see comment above^^. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

I would like to add that to minimise the specific configuration to `Kind` you should use `pv / pvc` this way the configuration on a real cluster will only differ in the definition of pv.

So if you configure extraMounts on your Kind cluster:

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraMounts:
    - hostPath: /home/bill/work/www
      containerPath: /www
```

Then on that cluster create PV and PVC:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-www
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /www/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-www
spec:
  volumeName: pv-www
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

After that you can use it in deployment like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: www
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-www
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /var/www
```

As a result your local `/home/bill/work/www` will be mounted to `/var/www` inside containers.

Comment: Where would the PV/PVC go on a kind cluster? Do you basically have to create a custom image on top of whatever it starts with (I think it's `node-image`)?

Answer (score 2):

From the example above

```yaml
...
  extraMounts:
    - hostPath: /home/bill/work/www
      containerPath: /www
...
```

So the path in your host (Laptop) is `/home/bill/work/www` and the path in the kubernetes node is `/www`

You are running kind and can make use of the fact it's running docker to check the nodes. Do a

```sh
docker ps -a
```

This will show you the kind docker images, which are all kubernetes nodes. So you can check the nodes by taking a CONTAINER_ID take from docker ps -a from above and do a

```sh
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

So now you have a shell running on that node. Check if the node has mounted you host filesystem properly

Just check with

```sh
ls /www
```

on the node. You should see the content of `/home/bill/work/www`

So what you have archived is that this part of the node filesystem is persisted by the host (Laptop). So you can destroy the cluster and recreate it with the same kind-config file. The node will remount and no information is lost.

So with this working setup you can make a persistan volume (pv) and claim this pv with a persistent volume claim (pvc) as described above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To set up a `Persistent Volume (PV)` and `Persistent Volume Claim (PVC)` shared by pods in a KIND cluster and keep the data persisted on your laptop, you can follow these steps:

Create a directory on your laptop that will serve as the PV.
Create a YAML file for the PV and PVC, specifying the path to the directory on your laptop as the source of the PV.
Apply the YAML file to your KIND cluster to create the PV and PVC.
In your pod specification, refer to the PVC by its name to mount the volume.

Here's an example of a YAML file for the PV and PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mypv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /path/to/your/laptop/directory
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

To apply the YAML file, run:

```
kubectl apply -f pv-pvc.yaml
```

In your pod specification, refer to the PVC by its name to mount the volume:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mypv
      mountPath: /path/in/container
  volumes:
  - name: mypv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mypvc
```

Note: You need to adjust and test it.